# Create email signature on office 365

Tags: email, email-signature

How can I create and deploy a standard email signature for my organisation on office 365?
I know of the option of manually creating a signature on the outlook desktop application, however, I want to create one and deploy for all users.

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you're referring to only the desktop application and not Webmail, a macro could likely be used to automate the deployment of the signature, however individual users would still need to open the macro on their machines _(there may be a way to deploy it in a completely automated way I'm not aware of)_.